# Correct way to use Java Synchronized?

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

I am building a stock system which will be used over an office LAN with multiple users. I have a query about using the synchronized keyword to update the stock correctly. What I wish to do is allow multiple users to update the stock but of course only allow one user to update at one time. I have created a method as follows for the update of stock:

```
public static synchronized boolean UpdateXYZStock(Stock so){
 //update code
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Thanks

S.

Comment: You need to provide far more detail here.

Comment: java synchronized does not span VMs.  You might consider letting your database handle synchronization issues like this.  Have UpdateStock() update the stock value in the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would lock on an *instance* of the object, not the class. i.e. don't lock a static method since you're locking the class. Further to that you may want to lock on an underlying object e.g.

```
private final Object writeLock = new Object();

public boolean UpdateXYZStock(Stock so) {
   synchronized(writeLock) {
      ...
   }
}
```

so you can control the granularity of the locking more finely (I'm assuming this method is on a component within a server and thus serving multiple clients)

Comment: If i lock on an underlying object, would this guarantee that the update code is only executed once, i.e. if there are mutiple users, they cannot all update at the same time, they have to wait in turn to update the stock?

Comment: That is right. Note also that you should make use of transactions and guaranteed atomicity in the database if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with synchronizing on a static method is that you are actually synchronizing on the entire class.  So if you have more than one static method in that class, the fact that this one is synchronized will prevent other classes from accessing any of the static methods until this one completes.

Otherwise is should accomplish what you want.

Comment: I do have other static methods in the class, so i think Brian's suggestion would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [ReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using `synchronized` that way is fine. It depends on where you are actually storing the data. If it is just stored within an objects, use this object's monitor, i.e. a non-static synchronized method.

If you store the data in a database, make sure all code updating this row in a table is using the same lock. This can be, as highlighted in the other reply, be an object that you make available through a static field. (Just don't use Strings to act as monitors).

Comment: The code is being stored in a database

Comment: are you using an optimistic or pessimistic locking protocol for the database?

Comment: I guess in this case, you don't need to synchronize at all. The persistence layer will figure out if you are updating stale data.